# Failed to package the game with compiled plugin, Missing precompiled manifest

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-development-kit, unreal-engine5

We packaged a plugin by following steps,

1. Packaged the plugin and added `bPrecompile=true` in `myplugin.build.cs`
   (Also tried to package the build with `-precompile` argument)
   Before packaging `myplugin.build.cs`,

   ```
    public class MyPlugin : ModuleRules
        {
            public MyPlugin(ReadOnlyTargetRules Target) : base(Target)
        {
            PCHUsage = ModuleRules.PCHUsageMode.UseExplicitOrSharedPCHs;
            PrecompileForTargets = PrecompileTargetsType.Any;
        bPrecompile = true;
   ```
2. After packaging, added `bUsePrecompiled = true` and `PrecompileForTargets = PrecompileTargetsType.Any;` in `myplugin.build.cs`
   after packaging `MyPlugin.build.cs`,

   ```
    public class MyPlugin : ModuleRules
    {
        public MyPlugin(ReadOnlyTargetRules Target) : base(Target)
        {
            PCHUsage = ModuleRules.PCHUsageMode.UseExplicitOrSharedPCHs;
            PrecompileForTargets = PrecompileTargetsType.Any;
        bUsePrecompiled = true;
   ```
3. Deleted C++ files & intermediate folder from the packaged plugin
   Used the plugin with a sample project (Included in the Plugin directory) and it is loaded without any issues.
   But when we tried to package the game or try to launch the game we are getting the following error:

   > `UATHelper`: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   ERROR: Missing precompiled manifest for 'MyPlugin'. This module was most likely not flagged for being included in a precompiled build - set `PrecompileForTargets = PrecompileTargetsType.Any;` in `MyPlugin.build.cs` to override.
   > `PackagingResults`: Error: Missing precompiled manifest for 'MyPlugin'. This module was most likely not flagged for being included in a precompiled build - set `PrecompileForTargets = PrecompileTargetsType.Any;` in `MyPlugin.build.cs` to override.

Comment: I have the same issue, where you able to solve it?